# How to calculate Content-Length header in rest assured?

Tags: java, rest, http, rest-assured

I am doing API testing of an web application where `Content-Length` is a compulsory header. Postman automatically generates that header. Header is generated by browser/android libraries too, but how to generate that header in rest-assured.

Writing any random value is generating error.

```java
String response = given()
                .header("Content-Length",**This value needed**)
                .header("Host","xyz.com")
                .header("Authorization","xyz")
                .header("Content-Type","application/json")
                .header("Accept","application/json" )
                .header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36" )
                .when()
                .post("/stores")
                .then().extract().response().asString();
```

Comment: Content-Length is not strictly required. If you do not set it, libraries will usually calculate if when they can (that is, when the length of the content is known at the time header fields are sent), otherwise (in HTTP/1.1) chunked encoding will be used, so Content-Length SHOULD NOT be sent.